# Which one to use - html label or Asp:label

Tags: asp.net

Which one to use

```
<label>Name</label>
<asp:Label Text="Name" runat="server"></asp:Label>
```

Genreally we are using label to show some text only(like not to many business logic on lables).
As a perfomance point of view which one to use.

Comment: It's called `label`, not `lable`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There would be very little to gain in performance between the two options. This is a micro-optimization.

But to answer the question - the straight markup would perform better, as there is no need to deserialize the control and operate on it server side.

In general, if you use a server side control, the server will need to do more work than with plain markup.

Answer (score 0):

It has different goals.

The Label is used with the `for` key which represents an alias of refer to another control

the asp:label is merely span generated.

as a speed matter : `label` wins.

Answer (score 0):

I would say you'd only need to use asp:label if you're planning to populat it dynamically (i.e. from code-behind) or if you want to use the "for" attribute with another server control (such as asp:TextBox). Otherwise, use the straight-html solution - your markup will be cleaner and it will be easier to identify the dynamic elements in the page.

Answer (score 0):

From a performance point of view: use the HTML `<label>`.

Besides that, a label is usually used together with another (input-) element, e.g. `<label for=...>`. The same is true for the ASP.NET label: `<asp:Label AssociatedControlId="..." .../>`.

If you want to render plain text, a simple `<span>` (or no HTML element at all) might be better suited. And the ASP.NET equivalent for that would be `<asp:Literal>` (e.g. if you need to access it from the code-behind).